# QT + winId() - Determine handle type

Tags: c++, cocoa, qt, macos-carbon

Is there a way, either at runtime or (preferably) by using preprocessor macros, to determine whether the handle returned by `QWidget::winId()` is a handle to a Cocoa window or a handle to a Carbon window?

Windows is obvious, but I'm more interested in Mac. A particular library I'm using already knows how to use the various handles, but it needs to know *which type* the handle is before using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are preprocessor defines in QtCore/qconfig.h for this.

Search for `QT_MAC_USE_COCOA` on the internet.

Comment: Perfect. For some reason [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366904/how-do-i-tell-on-mac-os-x-if-i-have-the-carbon-or-cocoa-version-of-qt-installed) didn't come up in my search. Thank you!